# XSLT stylesheet? Not sure how to write?

Tags: xslt

XML:

```
<tickets>
  <request day="tue">
    <ticket>
       <type>Tech Support</type>
       <cust>9045</cust>
       <status>pending</status>
    <ticket>
    <ticket>
       <type>Account Support</type>
       <cust>3344</cust>
       <status>resolved</status>
    <ticket>
  </request>
  <request day="wed">
    <ticket>
       <type>Tech Support</type>
       <cust>9944</cust>
       <status>new</status>
    <ticket>
    <ticket>
       <type>Billing</type>
       <cust>3344</cust>
       <status>pending</status>
    <ticket>
  </request>
</tickets>
```

How do I write a select="" to match all of the cust element values, non repeating (if there are most than 1 request)?

Comment: Your end <ticket> tags should be </ticket>

Comment: Please show your desired output.

Comment: Sounds like a grouping question (if I've understood correctly) - in which case the XSLT 2.0 solution is much easier than XSLT 1.0: you need to say which version you are using.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I write a select="" to match all of the cust element values,
>   non repeating (if there are most than 1 request)?

**Here is a complete, short and simple (no `xsl:for-each` and no long and unreadable lines) [Muenchian grouping](http://dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html) solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:key name="kCustByVal" match="cust" use="."/>

 <xsl:template match=
  "cust
     [generate-id()
     =
      generate-id(key('kCustByVal', .)[1])
     ]
  ">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:text> </xsl:text>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document** (having been made well-formed after numerous corrections):

```
<tickets>
    <request day="tue">
        <ticket>
            <type>Tech Support</type>
            <cust>9045</cust>
            <status>pending</status>
        </ticket>
        <ticket>
            <type>Account Support</type>
            <cust>3344</cust>
            <status>resolved</status>
        </ticket>
    </request>
    <request day="wed">
        <ticket>
            <type>Tech Support</type>
            <cust>9944</cust>
            <status>new</status>
        </ticket>
        <ticket>
            <type>Billing</type>
            <cust>3344</cust>
            <status>pending</status>
        </ticket>
    </request>
</tickets>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
9045 3344 9944
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="cust" match="/tickets/request/ticket/cust/text()" use="."/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="/tickets/request/ticket/cust/text()[generate-id()=generate-id(key('cust',.)[1])]">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```